# DataGridView - Search and Load by multiple columns and only 1 Search button

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview, tableadapter

For example I have a Table with 2 columns:

- Person Age
- Person Name

Right now, in the Query screen, I have 2 textboxes and 2 different search buttons:

- Textbox 1: SearchByAge
- Textbox 2: SearchbyName

I have a different code for each Search button:

- Button 1:

  Int32 Age;
  int.TryParse(this.SearchByAge.Text, out Age);
  this.personsTableAdapter.FillBy_queryAge(this.persons.personsTable, Age);
- Button 2:

this.personsTableAdapter.FillBy_queryName(this.persons.personsTable,this.SearchByName.Text);

As you can see, I have 2 different queries added in the Table Adapter: FillBy_queryAge and FillBy_queryName.

FillBy_queryAge: SELECT NAME, AGE FROM PERSONS WHERE (AGE = @AGE)
FillBy_queryName: SELECT NAME, AGE FROM PERSONS WHERE (NAME =@NAME)

I would like to use only 1 Search button which should look in both Textboxes and Load the DataGridView.

So it would be like:
Textbox 1: 20
Textbox 2: Anna

Click [Search] -> DataGridView is loaded with all the records where Age is 20 and Name is Anna.

Could you help, please?

Comment: If you have records displayed in a `DataGridView` you can apply an actual filter using the `RowFilter` property rather than rebuilding the datasource

Comment: Whats the declaration/definition of `FillBy_queryAge` and `FillBy_queryName` I would add that to the question

Comment: Hi @SlackGroverglow,


FillBy_queryAge: SELECT NAME, AGE FROM PERSONS WHERE (AGE = @AGE)
FillBy_queryName: SELECT NAME, AGE FROM PERSONS WHERE (NAME =@NAME)

Comment: Hi @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp,

Yep, you're right. 
But I am trying to learn how to do a search and load data gridview using multiple fields combined.

So in a project that I am developing, I am going to have maybe 20 TextBoxes in a Query screen. 
If the users leaves all of them empty, I will want to press [Search] and all records should be loaded.
But if some of them are populated, I will want to press [Search] and the data grid view should be loaded based on what I selected for all of them.

Comment: Is the query condition a direct assignment? Is the condition field always empty?

Answer (score 0):

I think that my main issue was how to handle a null value in one of those fields.
I used a query as below which solved the issue:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM PERSONS
 WHERE ((AGE LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@AGE, N'') + '%') OR(ISNULL(@AGE, '') = '')) 
       AND((NAME LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@NAME , N'') + '%') OR(ISNULL(@NAME , '') = ''))
```

The query builder automatically generates a bigger query with all possible scenarios. It may be too big if I use more fields but it works for now. Open to suggestions if there are better ways to do that avoiding performance issues.